# Activity Intent Permission Android M SDK 23

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

After switching from Build tool 22.0 to 23.1 i am getting error in start activity method.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

The error displaying in line `startActivity(callIntent)`is

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential
>   `SecurityException`

The same error was displaying for Location and Content resolver.
I solved it by checking condition like

```
    if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            || mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                   MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                   MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    location =  LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
```

What exactly the condition which is required in order to call **startActiivty** method ?
Please provide the details if possible for other permissions which may cause same type of errors.

Comment: Check this demo https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/Android-M-RuntimePermissionDemo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What exactly the condition which is required in order to call startActivity method?

Your code

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Uses the  `Intent.ACTION_CALL` intent, which requires a permission, namely the `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` one.

Normally you would put this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

but with api 23+ you have to check for permissions runtime, same as you did with the location:

```
if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. It's working fine. I have one doubt. Where exactly the permission will be granted to the app from user? If the above code written in background service how the dialog will appear like this https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/10304040/7883031/ee96f3f0-0630-11e5-8b77-44b696bea53a.png

Comment: Thanks for your time :)